# How to retain certain elements from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list as follows:

```
['X', 'table', 'product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']
```

From this list, I would like to retain the elements which only contain the word product in it and drop the rest.

The output must look like this:

```
['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']
```

I would like to know how can this be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and use [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) to determine if the string `product` is `in` the item being evaluated

```
l = ['X', 'table', 'product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']

print([i for i in l if 'product' in i])
# ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> >>> initial_list = ['X', 'table', 'product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']
> >>> product_list = [item for item in initial_list if "product" in item]
> >>> product_list
> ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']
> ```

- It's a *list comprehension* ([[Python 3.Docs]: Data Structures - List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))
- To test if whether a string contains a substring, ***in*** operator is used ([[Python 3.Docs]: Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension where you check for the existence of word `product` in each of the element

```
a = ['X', 'table', 'product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']
b = [i for i in a if 'product' in i]
# ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
s = pd.Series(['X', 'table', 'product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5'])
mask = s.str.match("product")
s[mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a **filter** such as:

```
lst = ['X', 'table', 'product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']
lst = filter(lambda x: 'product' in x, lst)
print(list(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the `regex` and then then `filter`

```
import re

mylist = ['X', 'table', 'product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']
r = re.compile(".*product")
newlist = list(filter(r.match, mylist))
print(newlist)
```

Outputs:

```
['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list commpersion method to find anything specific in a list. example

i want to find all students in this list:
ls = ['LSD','Student1','Student2','Student1231','jj',21]

i find it with list the method *in* with specific criteria

print([s for s in ls if 'Student' in s])

output=['Student1', 'Student2', 'Student1231']

You can use the same method to find product in a list:
product_ls = ['X', 'table', 'product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']

print([p for p in product_ls if 'product' in p])